# Cannot require luacom library in lua script

Tags: c++, shell, lua

I am new to Lua programming language. I installed *Lua for Windows v5.1.5-52*. I want to use *luacom* library to run shell script. Here is my code,

```
local luacom = require('luacom');

local shell = luacom.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell:Run ('echo 123', 0)
```

which throws the following error:

> lua: COM exception:(.\src\library\tLuaCOM.cpp,398):The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

I looked for *tLuaCOM.cpp* file, but could not find it, not even folder *src*. Though I found *luacom.dll* in *clibs* folder.

Is there any workaround with this problem?

Comment: [tLuaCOM.cpp](https://github.com/davidm/luacom/blob/9962eb574ddb34692eb4503fe67fd7d363ff20a0/src/library/tLuaCOM.cpp#L384) is a luacom source file, so it's probably not on your PC, except you've build it yourself. The error comes from one of the calls - either `CreateObject` or `Run`? Try `shell:Run ('cmd.exe')`or `cmd /c "echo 123"`

Comment: @A.A Hi, I tried *shell:Run('cmd /c "echo 123"')* and it worked. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tLuaCOM.cpp](https://github.com/davidm/luacom/blob/9962eb574ddb34692eb4503fe67fd7d363ff20a0/src/library/tLuaCOM.cpp#L384) is a *luacom* source file, so it's probably not on your PC, except you've build it yourself.

The error comes from one of the calls - either `CreateObject()` or `Run`.

The [Run Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  helps says that it starts processes:

> The **Run** method starts a program running in a new Windows process.

but [`echo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc772462%28v%3dws.11%29) is a shell command, not an executable, so you have to start an instance of the [Windows command interpreter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771320(v=ws.10)) and pass your command like:

```
shell:Run('cmd /c "echo 123"')
```